# "Light of Other Days" sequel

Tags: books, the-light-of-other-days

At the end of Baxter's and Clarke's "The Light of other Days", we see that our DNA was saved from destruction by an earlier terrestrial species.

I'm looking for a sequel. These are the details that I recall:

- Wormcam technology has progressed to the point that DNA samples and psychic prints can be retrieved from historical subjects, new bodies cloned, and minds imprinted: basically, travel into their future.
- The scientist discover a dinosaur civilization and bring some forward.  They have a toast they like to use: "Top of the Food Chain to You!".
- The dino's try to take over our civilization and we stop them.
- We are also terraforming Venus into proto-earth conditions so that they can save the original earth species that saved our DNA at the end of the other book.

Any of this ring a bell?

Comment: This question is very confusing.  It seems like you're asking a [tag:story-identification] question, but you're starting by stating it's a sequel to a story that didn't have a sequel.

Comment: I know everybody says there is no sequel, Google says there isn't one.  So maybe I made it up in my mind, except I'm not that creative<g>.

Comment: P K Dick has written a couple of stories with this topic. I mean, non the dinosaur civilization, but the sudden appearance or disappearance of something. It usually doesn't forebear well.